# jQuery deferred complicated sequential loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops, deferred, sequential

I've tried to read many answers on stackoverflow, but most problems seem to be a bit simpler than mine. What I want to do is:

1. execute a for loop of varying length which retrieves table rows through an ajax query.
2. once i've got all the rows, I want to retrieve statistics, through another ajax query
3. once i've got the stats, i need to send a message to the server, which executes another call to free database memory (oh yes, i do communicate with some sort of oldstyle webservice behind all this).

Here is my code:

```
    var chainedPromise = new Array();
    //Build a .then() chain by assignment
    for (i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) {
        (function(i){
            chainedPromise = $.when().then(function(){
                return get_results_ajax(table, idRows, requests[i-1], requests[i], type, cfg.siteroot);
            });
        })(i);
    }

    var Promise = $.when(chainedPromise).then(function(){
        return get_stats_ajax(table, idRows, type, cfg.siteroot);
    }).then(function() {
        return get_free_ajax(table,idRows, type, cfg.siteroot);
    });
```

requests contains a list of numbers : [100, 200, 300, 400] up to 5000.
Each request should send back 100 table rows. This works correctly.

What does not work is that the stats and free operation are executed AFTER I have retrieved all the data. So the chaining of the last two calls needs to be done differently, obviously, but I do not understand how exactly this should be done.

The ajax calls are made like this:

```
function get_results_ajax(table, idRows, start, stop, type, siteroot) {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    var request = jQuery.ajax({
        type        : 'POST'
        url         : siteroot+"/index.php?page=ajax",
        data        : "type="+type+"&idRows="+idRows+"&start="+start+"&stop="+stop,
        dataType    : 'json',
    });

    request.success(function(data) {
        table.rows.add(data).draw();
    });

    request.done(function(msg, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (jqXHR.status === 200) {
            deferred.resolve(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
        console.log("Returned data from " + start + " to " + stop);
    });

    request.fail(function(msg, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("The server is taking too long to respond. Start: " + start + " Stop: " + stop);
        deferred.reject("HTTP error: " + jqXHR.status);
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Comment: Your 1, 2 and 3 sounds like [Reactive Extensions.](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) with some custom ajax functions.

Answer (score 0):

First off, there are several mistakes in here:

```
var chainedPromise = new Array();
//Build a .then() chain by assignment
for (i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) {
    (function(i){
        chainedPromise = $.when().then(function(){
            return get_results_ajax(table, idRows, requests[i-1], requests[i], type, cfg.siteroot);
        });
    })(i);
}

var Promise = $.when(chainedPromise).then(function(){
    return get_stats_ajax(table, idRows, type, cfg.siteroot);
}).then(function() {
    return get_free_ajax(table,idRows, type, cfg.siteroot);
});
```

1. `chainedPromise` is an array and you want it to remain an array so you can pass it to `$.when()`.  To add a value to the array, you use `.push()`.  You are just assigning to `chainedPromise` which just replaces it with a new value and it is no longer an array.
2. `get_results_ajx()` returns a promise so you can just use that promise directly.  No need to use `$.when().then(...)` in front of it.
3. `$.when()` doesn't accept an array directly (stupid design decision by jQuery if you ask me), but rather takes a sequence of separate arguments, so to pass it an array, you have to use `.apply()` to turn the array into a list of arguments.
4. When you have an array you want to process into an array of promises, it's a whole lot easier to use `.map()` than a `for` loop.
5. You have a loop with an array index that starts at 0 and you try to reference `requests[i-1]` which will give you `undefined` on the first iteration of the loop because `i-1 === -1`.  I don't know what you intended for that first iteration.  Do you mean to start your iteration at `i = 1` instead?

So, with the exception that you still need to fix item 5 above, all that initial code can be changed to this:

```
var promiseArray = requests.map(function(item, i) {
    return get_results_ajax(table, idRows, requests[i-1], requests[i], type, cfg.siteroot);
});

$.when.apply($, promiseArray).then(function() {
    return get_stats_ajax(table, idRows, type, cfg.siteroot);
}).then(function() {
    return get_free_ajax(table,idRows, type, cfg.siteroot);
});
```

Then, your `get_results_ajax()` is making things way more complicated than need be.  jQuery's `$.ajax()` already returns a promise.  You can use it directly and you do not need to create your own deferred.  In fact, wrapping it in another deferred is referred to as a [promise anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns).

So, this:

```
function get_results_ajax(table, idRows, start, stop, type, siteroot) {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    var request = jQuery.ajax({
        type        : 'POST'
        url         : siteroot+"/index.php?page=ajax",
        data        : "type="+type+"&idRows="+idRows+"&start="+start+"&stop="+stop,
        dataType    : 'json',
    });

    request.success(function(data) {
        table.rows.add(data).draw();
    });

    request.done(function(msg, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (jqXHR.status === 200) {
            deferred.resolve(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
        console.log("Returned data from " + start + " to " + stop);
    });

    request.fail(function(msg, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("The server is taking too long to respond. Start: " + start + " Stop: " + stop);
        deferred.reject("HTTP error: " + jqXHR.status);
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Can become this:

```
function get_results_ajax(table, idRows, start, stop, type, siteroot) {
    return jQuery.ajax({
        type        : 'POST'
        url         : siteroot+"/index.php?page=ajax",
        data        : "type="+type+"&idRows="+idRows+"&start="+start+"&stop="+stop,
        dataType    : 'json',
    }).then(function(data) {
        table.rows.add(data).draw();
    });
}
```

Things I changed:

1. Return the `jQuery.ajax()` promise directly.  No need to create a deferred.
2. Use the promise standard `.then()` instead of the jQuery proprietary `.done()`.  Good thing to do going forward since jQuery supports `.then()` and it is now the standard in ES6.
3. When returning the promise directly, it will automatically propagate errors back in the returned promise.  You don't have to do that manually.